# How to make horizonatl aligned with css at the same line two block of the vutify

Tags: html, css

I am working on project with vutify I have created two blocks a div into a v-row I want  cols into a row to display aligned at the same line without space on the bottom.

I am sharing my code:

```css
.sub-heading {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.625rem;
    color: #F1191D;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 3.85rem;
}
.short-text{
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.125rem;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #201E1C;
}
.vertical{
    width: 2px !important;
     height: 106px !important;
     border-color: #201E1C !important;
     margin-top: 58px;

}
```

```html
<template>
 <v-container fluid > 
     <v-row justify="center">
         <v-col cols="12" md="6">
             <v-row class="justify-center align-center  test">  
                 <v-col cols="12" md="5"  sm="6" class="mb-6">           
                         <h4  class="sub-heading" >Test </h4>
                          <h2 >Test1  
                          <br> Post recenti  </h2> 
                  </v-col>   

                 <v-divider vertical class="vertical    hidden-sm-and-down  justify-center align-center">  </v-divider> 
         
                    <v-col cols="12" md="7" sm="6" >
                        <p class="short-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Felis, pharetra donec id velit tincidunt sed hac fringilla. In est ac fermentum cras. Neque viverra ultricies in at ipsum iaculis pretium, viverra felis. Pretium porttitor leo vulputate imperdiet aliquet etiam eget sit. </p>                     
                 </v-col >
             </v-row>
        </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

This is  what I have created until now.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But we want first col and second col to aligned at the same line into a row.

Any idea
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sQOW.png

Comment: Can you make the `line-height` shorter on `<h2>Test1 Post recenti</h2>` so that it matches the paragraph? Or, the opposite way, increase the line-height slightly on your paragraph (those lines are kinda close together).

Comment: Thanks but on  the figma I shoud to use this line-height.

Comment: Are you wanting the bottom of the text to align - if so it's going to be hard as even with playing with line-height, your columns seem responsive so what may work for width won't work for them all

Comment: @Pete is correct though. It isn't a perfect solution. It's my fault. I only just noticed your requirement for it all to be level at the bottom. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ Pete I don't understend we can do this point. Thanks for your answer?